# Critical problem with ubuntu hard disk

Tags: boot

Getting below bug, what should I do ?

Very critical,unable to mount HDD,

[image]

More details, http://paste.ubuntu.com/6678256/

Comment: for more information paste.ubuntu.com/6678256/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as a bug. Do you have any other red colored lines like this ? (scroll down).

The `Read Error Rate` attribute of S.M.A.R.T reads

> Stores data related to the rate of hardware read errors that occurred
>   when reading data from a disk surface.

If you have other red attributes as well, this might mean that your HDD is near to the end (death). Do a backup quickly.

Read in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) about the S.M.A.R.T attributes. Be informed that not all attributes are identical to all HDDs. Sometimes you must search vendor specific meanings.